# how to make multilpe line in place holder and style them differently

Tags: html

What I want is for some of the input fields to have two place holder in given image below exactly same like picture given below. I have tried a lot but nothing works.

[image: HTML form image]

```html
 <form class="subscribe-form">
    <div class="personal-information">
        <select name = "country" id="country">
            <span>Country</span>
            <option value ="US" >US</option>
            <option value = "India">India</option>
            <option value = "Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
         </select>
         <select name ="cardType" id="cardType">
            <option value = "Amex">Amex</option>
            <option value = "Visa">Visa</option>
            <option value = "Master card">Master card</option>
         </select>
        <input type="text" id="cnum" name="address" placeholder="Card Number"/>
        <div class="date-container">
            <div class="card-data">
                <input type="text" id="expyear" name="expyear" placeholder="Expiry Date">
                <input type="text" id="csc" name="csc" placeholder="CSC"/>
            </div>
            <div class="name-data">
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"/>
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Billing-deatails">
       <h3>Billing Address</h3>
        <input type="text" id="line1" name="line2" placeholder="Address Line 1"/>
        <input type="text" id="line2" name="line2" placeholder="Address Line 2"/>
        <input type="text" id="Town/city" name="Town/city" placeholder="Town/city"/>
            <div class="numberType">
                <select name = "country" id="country2">
                    <option value ="US" >US</option>
                    <option value = "India">India</option>
                    <option value = "Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                 </select>
                <input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Postcode"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-information">
        <h5>Contact Information</h5>
            <div class="number-info">
                <select name = "phoneType" id="phoneType">
                    <option value ="Mobile" >Mobile</option>
                 </select>
                <input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="+65"/>
            </div>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="subscribe-btn">
    <button  type="submit">SUBSCRIBE</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: There are no multiple placeholder things. You have to use label and placeholder all together to create these inputs.

Comment: but how  can use label inside text field

Comment: do we have bootstrap class for this

Answer (score 1):

There are no multiple `placeholder` things in `HTML`. You have to use the `Label` with custom `CSS`.You can try the below code but I have done it for only one `Select box` you can use the same for others. You can edit the `CSS` as per your convenience.

```css
.select-wrap 
{
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 5px 5px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#ebebeb;
}

.select-wrap label
{
  font-size:10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #777;
  padding: 2px 8px 0;
}

select
{
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  border:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrap">
  <label>Country</label>
  <select name = "country" id="country" style="width: 100%;">
      <span>Country</span>
      <option value ="US" >US</option>
      <option value = "India">India</option>
      <option value = "Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
   </select>
</div>
```